# How can if find the size of a file prior to upload, with the help of jquery?

Tags: php, jquery

I want to check the file size before uploading it, so that i can restrict the users before uploading. I want it use the jquery, but please suggest some thing else, if it is not possible in that way.
I am using PHP at backend.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307679/using-jquery-restricting-file-size-before-uploading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't with Javascript, but you can using a Flash based uploader such as [SWFUpload](http://www.swfupload.org/).

Answer (score 3):

You can't check file size with Javascript. This is a security restriction. The only way you can do it is only using server-side scripting.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. It's a security restriction in Javascript/HTML. Best what you can do is to use a real programming language for which you can write client-side applications which you on its turn can embed in a web page, such as a (signed!) [Java Applet](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/deployment/applet/) or [Java Web Start](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/deployment/webstart/) (aka JNLP).

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible via JavaScript. You could try to use any kind of browser plugin to perform these test. FlashPlayer offers these kind of possibilities.