# how to display error message in image upload

Tags: php, html

How do I display "file size is greater than the specified" and "Please upload only Image" message to user? I tried with the below code

`if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 2097152) { // if file is larger than we want to allow
    echo "ERROR: Your file was larger than 2MB in file size.";`

but that didn't work.

```
<form action="" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" ><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my php code below. It works by adding `else
   {
    echo "Invalid file";
    }` at the end but i wanted to show individual error to the user...txs

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 2097152)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
{

if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
{
echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
}
else
{
echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 2097152) { // if file is larger than we want to allow
echo "ERROR: Your file was larger than 2MB in file size.";
}
if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
{
echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
}
else
{
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
"upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
echo "your photo has been uploaded successfully!";
}
}
}
?>
```

Comment: is the problem (1) your error message not showing or (2) error message shown but image still uploaded?

Comment: @ariefbayu the image upload works but it doesn't show error msgs.. it's problem(1)

Comment: what is the output from this line: `echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";`?

Comment: it outputs just the uploaded image size..for example Size: 13.865234375 kB

Comment: I mean, on your bigger than 2MB file test, what is the output? You must test your code against file bigger than 2MB.

Comment: the problem is that, it doesn't show anything..

Comment: @Magna, did you get this resolved?

Comment: @cryptic Nope...I'm just going with the original code...I couldn't solve it..

Comment: @Magna, did neither of the below answer solve it then? Even the logic error I pointed out?

Comment: best is you should do in jquery validation plug in https://stackoverflow.com/a/45163290/8148100

Answer (score 1):

```
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 2097152)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
```

There you are checking to see if the filesize is **less** than the max allowed. So if it is more that if() statement will return FALSE and the rest of code will not run. That being the case inside that if() block you then do:

```
if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 2097152)
```

Which you check if it is **more**, but you have *already* validated the size with the first if() so a file too large won't trigger the error as it would have *already failed* the first if()

So to fix it you would remove this line, so you can output the error individually:

```
 && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 2097152)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think precedence should be like

1. Checking file has error or not
2. Checking file is an image or not
3. checking file size is less than 2MB or not
4. Checking file already exists or not

so i prefer following

```
<?php
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {//Checking file has error or not
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
} else {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

    if (($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")) { //Checking file is an image or not

        if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 2097152) { //checking file size is less than 2MB or not
            if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) { //Checking file already exists or not

                echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
            } else {
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
                echo "Your photo has been uploaded successfully!";
            }
        } else {
            echo "ERROR: Your file was larger than 2MB in file size.";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Please upload only Image.";
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you wanna go for client side validation for file upload, but if you want to do so, there is a nice jQuery plug-in.

http://adamsanderson.github.com/jQuery-File-Validator/

It will be helpful. You can customize the code to validate for either of or both of - size and type of file.

Comment: you can see demo on above web-page itself.