# Javascript to check filesize before upload in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, extjs

Is it possible to use Javascript to check for a file's size (at the client side) before it is actually uploaded to the server?

The application is built on EXTJS and Java and is restricted to usage by Internet Explorere 7 on Windows XP machines. No usage of activeX is allowed.

The workflow is as such:
User selects a file to upload.
Validation kicks in immediately to check for file type and filesize.
If filesize exceeds limit, the GUI will prompt with error.
If filesize is within the limit, the full filepath will be passed to the server end (java servlet) to be uploaded.

Is the filesize check and reading of full file path possible to be achieved with javascript?

Answer (score 4):

It is possible with ActiveX Objects.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function getSize()
{
    var myFSO = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    var filepath = document.upload.file.value;
    var thefile = myFSO.getFile(filepath);
    var size = thefile.size;
    alert(size + " bytes");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="upload">
<input type="file" name="file">
<input type="button" value="Size?" onClick="getSize();">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. As I've mentioned in my first post, not going the ActiveX way. :)

Answer (score 3):

There's currently no way to portably check the size of an uploaded file from the web browser. The [HTML5 File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_files_from_web_applications) makes this possible, but that's not available in MSIE7 -- it's currently on track for MSIE10.

There is intentionally no way to determine the full path of an uploaded file, as that may include sensitive information, like the name of the end user.

Comment: I'm looking for PRE-uploading the file. For example when I've selected the file and then PRIOR to the actual upload to get the filesize and the full filepath.

Comment: As I've noted, there is currently no way to detect the file size, and there is (and will likely never be) any way to determine the local path.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you can't is because it would be bad if browsers, and javascript, could access the clients filesystem.

This is actively denied and can be seen as an attack.

[Using jQuery, Restricting File Size Before Uploading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307679/using-jquery-restricting-file-size-before-uploading)

Comment: How about another method. Say I have an input form, find the full filepath first and then feed it to the filesize checking code. I looked at uploadify, swfupload, fancifulupload and yuiuploader. I can't seem to be able to "feed" the full filepath into them.

Answer (score -3):

Please try below code,

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$("document").ready(function(){
        $("#myFile1").change(function() {

        var f1=document.getElementById("myFile1").value;
        if((f.size||f.fileSize)==09765625)
        {
        alert("file size is less than 1mb");
        }
        else
        {
        alert("file size should not exceed more than 1mb");
                $(this).val($.data(this, 'f'));
        return false;
        }

            });
});
})
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type='file' name="file" id="myFile1" />

</body>
</html>
```