# How to get file size before uploaded in IE?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get a file size before upload file in IE without ActiveX or like this but i can not find any solution to resolved this problem.

How to get file size before uploaded in IE?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get file size before uploading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7497404/get-file-size-before-uploading)

Comment: What version of IE are you using?

Comment: ah, sorry: even better duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7279055/javascript-to-check-filesize-before-upload-in-internet-explorer. You did zero research, did you?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IE10+ then you can use a FileReader. See following for more information:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader
- http://html5please.com/#file

This does beg some other questions among the first I think of are:

- How are you going to support older browsers?
- Do you need to support other browsers or mobile browsers?

Comment: Thank's for your answer