# File Upload, jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using jQuery, Restricting File Size Before Uploading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307679/using-jquery-restricting-file-size-before-uploading)

When a user clicks on the file select button on an input element with it's type "file" is it possible to determine the file size, and other information about the file, before the user presses upload?

For example, and event that occurs after the user has added their file ready to be uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons ajax / javascript isn't allowed to access the file stream or file properties before or during upload.

Refer this link [Using jQuery, Restricting File Size Before Uploading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307679/using-jquery-restricting-file-size-before-uploading)

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use flash or other unreliable and unrequired software, which would just ruin user's experience. Otherwise, it's not possible