# Pyramid how to handle an xhr.abort()

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, file-upload, pyramid

I have an image uploader that after the image is uploaded it is processed.  The uploading and processing can take more than 5 seconds on a slow connection.  I added a way for the user to abort the upload using `xhr.abort()`.

The problem I have is once the upload is aborted my pyramid application will continue to process the image, save it to disk, and add the record to the database.

Is there a way for my view to know that the user called `xhr.abort()` so I can clean up.

Answer (score 1):

You should receive an event called 'abort' on the xhr-object.
If this doesn't work, readystatechange should be fired in every situation.

Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-abort-method

**Edit:** How about sending an AJAX-request when the "onabort"-event fires? Then you could undo your changes serverside.
To check whether the file arrived complete at the server, you could get the filesize on client-side and send it to the server (http://stackoverflow.com/a/5444716/725629).

Comment: This explains how it is supposed to work client side.  I am not sure how that message comes across server side.

Comment: oh sorry i hadn't read your question exactly.. so you want to know how you can "capture" an abort serverside?