# jquery to verify file type and file size before submitting

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using jQuery, Restricting File Size Before Uploading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307679/using-jquery-restricting-file-size-before-uploading)

Is there a good jquery script or other method that can verify file size and file type before uploading a file to a server? I've tried looking all over but never found anything to do something like this.

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307679/using-jquery-restricting-file-size-before-uploading?rq=1 it seems to be duplicate question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest the following:

```
$('input:file').change(
    function(e) {
        var files = e.originalEvent.target.files;
        for (var i=0, len=files.length; i<len; i++){
            console.log(files[i].fileName, files[i].type, files[i].fileSize);
        }
    });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/eHNJg/).

As JavaScript can't remove files from the selected `fileList` object, you'd have to perform checks against the file attributes and prompt the user to deselect files that would be considered invalid due to file-type or file-size (and, obviously, prevent the form submitting):

```
$('input:file').change(
    function(e) {
        var files = e.originalEvent.target.files;
        for (var i=0, len=files.length; i<len; i++){
            var n = files[i].name,
                s = files[i].size,
                t = files[i].type;

            if (s > 100) {
                console.log('Please deselect this file: "' + n + '," it\'s larger than the maximum filesize allowed. Sorry!');
            }
        }
    });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/eHNJg/4/).

(This last code tested and working in Chromium 19 and Firefox 15, both on Ubuntu 11.04.)

Comment: I keep getting :undefinedimage/jpegundefined. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Norman: I've amended the second code block, which seems to work reliably in Firefox 15 and Chromium 19; I'm unable to test IE, but I suspect that it'll fail in versions lower than 9 or 10.

Comment: This time it's working well. I'll do some testing and see how things go.

Comment: Good luck; and let me/us know how your testing goes!

Answer (score 3):

Taken from here: [How can I upload files asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery)

I'm not sure if it would work on old browsers (like IE6/7 (duh, who the hell still uses those)) but you might try it. It should work on all modern browsers though. Try it:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input name="file" type="file" />
<input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
$(':file').change(function(){
    var file = this.files[0];
    name = file.name;
    size = file.size;
    type = file.type;
    //your validation
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There's the [jQuery File Upload plugin](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/), no need to reinvent the wheel. It has an `acceptFileTypes` option that allows you to provide a regular expression to match a given file type, as well as a `maxFileSize` option, e.g.:

```
{
  fileTypes: /^(gif|jpeg|png)$/,
  maxFileSize: 20000000 // 20MB
}
```

Note, however, that this will only work for web browsers that support the **[File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/File)**. Otherwise, you'd have to verify the file type on the server-side.

Comment: I've been playing around with this from July since I started work on this project. Problem  is, it's too complicated to customize. Weather it's the full version or basic version.

Comment: @Norman: I agree that it can be a bit difficult to get started with this plugin. I've recently used it on a project. What do you want to customize?

Comment: What I want is simple but kinda tricky to explain here :-) Maybe I'll email you :) ?

Comment: Well, can you try to explain? ;-)