# Grabbing an input value with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to grab the file size, of a selected file, before a user submits the form. I am trying to use JQuery to do this so that I can prevent form submission if the file size is too big. But I can't get my code to work right.

My Jquery on form submit:

```
var size = $("photo-input")[0].files[0].size;
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307679/using-jquery-restricting-file-size-before-uploading

Answer (score 1):

You should prefix `#`, assuming you want to select on the basis of `ID`

```
 var size = $("#photo-input")[0].files[0].size;
```

HTML has no element as `photo-input`