# golang template upload file how to validate the file is empty

Tags: file, templates, go, upload

I am a beginner with go-lang. I met a problem when I uploaded a file with html template. I google a lot but not solved.

```
<input  type="file" name="myfile"/>
```

Use func (*Request) FormFile get the file.

```
file, header, err := req.FormFile("receipt")
```

But how to validate the file whether it is empty from server side? I know I can read request.Body to find whether myfile is empty.

Is there a better way to implement it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to know the size of the file until you read it. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/280702/1892060):

> To read the file content is the only reliable way. Having said that, if the content-lenght is present and is too big, to close the connection would be a reasonable thing to do.

So I guess you'll have to read a part of the content into a small temporary buffer and look at the size.

If you want to validate, whether the user even sent a file, you can check against [`http.ErrMissingFile`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ErrMissingFile):

```
    file, header, err := r.FormFile("f")
    switch err {
    case nil:
        // do nothing
    case http.ErrMissingFile:
        log.Println("no file")
    default:
        log.Println(err)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't find the length of a file without reading it. (You can try to use Content-Length header, but you have to know that it can be modified and thus not reliable).

Here is how you can get the file size:

```
file, handler, err := r.FormFile("receipt") // r is *http.Request
var buff bytes.Buffer
fileSize, err := buff.ReadFrom(file)
fmt.Println(fileSize) // this will return you a file size.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file size from the header variable (in your example), which is a [FileHeader type](https://golang.org/pkg/mime/multipart/#FileHeader), returned by [FormValue](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.FormFile), and contains the size of the file:

```
file, header, err := req.FormFile("receipt")
if err != nil || header.Size == 0 {
    // file was not sent
} else {
    // process file
}
```

Though I'm not sure how reliable is this data in terms of security (I guess an attacker could fake the headers sent to the server maliciously).